# Blinking purple screen New installation Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, nvidia, 20.04

I have an old acer pc and I wanted to install ubuntu 20.04 after trying, so I did the installationi ticked normal installation update and graphic something then I installed in a hard drive everything went well when i restarted it demanded my password but when I hit enter blinking purple screen appear mouse doesnt work keyboard either
Help me I am stuck

Graphic card geforce 9200

CPU: amd athlon II X3 435

Thanks for your time

Edit: product: Aspire X3400

*-display

graphics card:
                       nVidia C77 [GeForce 8200]

Primary display adapter: #12

Edit2:the problem is partially solved now ican boot to ubuntu but only on VGA I did that by using 'sudo apt-get purge nvidia*'
but now i dont have a driver for my card

lspci | grep VGA
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation C77 [GeForce 8200] (rev a2)

(I have a 9200 )
how to correct this problem?

Comment: I'd suggest you recheck. with _sudo lshw | grep product | head -n1 && sudo lshw | grep display && sudo lspci -v -s $(lspci | grep ' VGA ' | cut -d" " -f 1) | sudo hwinfo  --gfxcard --short_  then highlight the resulting text, copy with Ctrl-Shift-C then return here, click [edit], and paste the results into your Question so all the facts we need are in the question. Also please confirm you have at least 4GB of RAM as that's a System Requirement for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]